# Populate email "to" field with address from reactive-table in Meteor

Tags: email, meteor

I have a reactive-table in Meteor that lists usernames and email addresses from the users collection.  I want to click on the email address and have a modal pop up with that email address filled in the "to" field.

Template with reactive table and email modal:

```
<template name="Compete">
{{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover" settings=settings }} 
{{> emailModalTemplate settings.fields}}
</template>
```

settings helper:

```
Template.Compete.helpers({

settings: function(){
    if (Meteor.user()){
        var col = Meteor.users.find({ }, {fields: {profile:1, emails:1} } );
        var email = 'emails.0.address';
        return {
            collection: col,
            showFilter: false,
            showNavigation: 'never',
            fields: [{
                    key: 'profile.userName',
                    label: 'Player'
                }, {
                    key: email,
                    label: 'Email',
                    fn: function(email){ 
                        return new Spacebars.SafeString(
                            '<a href="#" class="sndLnk" value="'+email+'">'+email+'</a>'
                            );
                    }
                }]
        };
    }
},
```

And here is the email modal template:

```
<template name="emailModalTemplate">    
<div class="modal fade" id="emailModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Send Email</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                    
            <form role="form" id="email-form">
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="{{addToAddr}}">
                <input type="text"  id="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject">
                <textarea id="inputBody" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>             
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>      
</template>
```

At this point, the {{addToAddr}} helper is just console logging "this" but all I can get back are the actual keys from the reactive table settings, but not the values.  Am I passing in the right thing by passing in the reactive table helper?

What else could I pass in to the email modal template to get the actual email values that I can then use to populate the email to address field?

**EDIT: One last note to add:**
My click event is as follows:

```
'click .sndLnk': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    console.log( $(e.currentTarget).attr('value') );
    $('#emailModal').modal('show');
}
```

The console.log here accurately shows the email address I want to pass in, but how do I pass that in to the email modal form?  I assumed via the helper, but maybe that's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered with it some more and resolved it by setting a session variable in a new "external" helper function, "external" in that it is just a var I set, not within Template.myTemplate.helpers:

```
var openEmailModal = function(email) {
  Session.set('theEmailAddr', email);
  $('#emailModal').modal('show');
}
```

Then I modified the click event to call the new var/function:

```
'click .sndLnk': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    var email = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');       
    openEmailModal(email);
}
```

At the end of the day this seems pretty basic, I made it into much more than it was I guess...  Thanks to all who viewed.